# How to add an attribute to select option with javascript, jquery or css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having some html which is generated automatically, so I can't change it in the html directly. But it's basically this:

```
    <select name="field2" id="id_18_gen" >
        <option value="{1,2}" >Please choose...</option>
        <option value="1" >correct</option>
        <option value="2" >false</option>
    </select>
```

Now I would like to add the hidden and the disabled attribute to the first option:

```
    <option value="{1,2}" hidden disabled >Please choose...</option>
```

I've tried several things for example:

```
    let e = document.getElementById(element);
    e.options["{1,2}"].hidden ="true";
```

or

```
    $("#" +element+ "option[value=" + "{1,2}" + "]").hide();
```

But nothing worked. A javascript or Jquery solution would be great, but css would be alright too.

Answer (score 0):

check if the below code works

```
let e = document.getElementbyId('id_18_gen').firstElementChild;
e.disabled = true;
e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)** method.

```
firstop.setAttribute("hidden",""); 
firstop.setAttribute("disabled","");
```

```js
var firstop = document.querySelector("#id_18_gen option:first-child");
firstop.setAttribute("hidden",""); 
firstop.setAttribute("disabled","");
```

```html
 <select name="field2" id="id_18_gen" >
     <option value="{1,2}" >Please choose...</option>
     <option value="1" >correct</option>
     <option value="2" >false</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

e.setAttribute('attribute', value).
To select an specific option, it's e.options[index] or e.options.item(index) (the same) or by it's id width e.options.namedItem(id).setAttribute(....)

To find a specific option by value:

```
e.options.map((option, index) => {
 if (option.value == '{1,2}')
  option.setAttribute('hidden', true);
})
```

or better with queryselector:

```
document.querySelector('#id_18_gen option[value={1,2}]')
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can use:

```
$('#id_18_gen option').first().attr({"hidden":"","disabled":""});
```

```js
$(function() {
    const firstOpt = $('#id_18_gen option').first();
    console.log( "Before:", firstOpt[0] );
    firstOpt.attr({"hidden":"","disabled":""});
    console.log( "After:", firstOpt[0] );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="field2" id="id_18_gen" >
   <option value="{1,2}" >Please choose...</option>
   <option value="1" >correct</option>
   <option value="2" >false</option>
</select>
```